# Can MySQL SELECT include timezone or offset on datetime columns

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone

I would like retrieve results from a datetime column in a format that includes a timezone like '2023-07-17 12:34:56 PDT' and have not found a way to achieve this. The [date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function doesn't include timezones.

Is there a way to achieve this?  I'm particularly looking at selecting rows from multiple timezones and having the Daylight Savings calculated correctly.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `deleteme` (
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB

SET time_zone = 'UTC';

-- Note that Daylight Savings in America/Los_Angeles begins on March 13th, 2023,
-- so when I go to SELECT from these in that timezone, the second value should
-- have Daylight Savings calculated, but not the first.

INSERT INTO `deleteme` VALUES ('2023-03-01 12:34:56'),('2023-04-01 12:34:56');
```

If I use the [`convert_tz`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function, it gets the time values right.  Note that both values were inserted with `12:34:56` UTC, and the value returned from April correctly takes Daylight Savings into consideration.

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp`, 'UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles') FROM `deleteme`;
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp`, 'UTC', 'America/Los_Angeles') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 2023-03-01 04:34:56                                   |
| 2023-04-01 05:34:56                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'd like to execute a SELECT statement, and have it return values that include the appropriate timezone abbreviation. Like this:

```
mysql> SELECT <what_do_i_put_here> FROM `deleteme`;
+---------------------------+
| what_do_i_put_here        |
+---------------------------+
| 2023-03-01 04:34:56 PST   |
| 2023-04-01 05:34:56 PDT   |
+---------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: no you ca not, you can save the data in the database, but mysql would convert the data to utc, and the when you select he data ot will be converted to local time, in which it will add +01:00 for example auto matically

Comment: Since there was no way to do this, I create a feature request which may be added in MySQL 8.1 (see https://bugs.mysql.com/111783)